# too much time in reading sms from database and storing it in to text file

Tags: android, sms

I'm reading sms record from database and write them into text file. But it takes too much time 3 to 4 mins to read n write 3500 records. If records are much more than that it takes plenty of time which is not appreciable. My code is:

```
final Cursor cur1 = c.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null, "date ASC");
final int size = cur1.getCount();

final int sleeptimer = size;

final SMS [] sms = new SMS[size];

final String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "account.txt";

FileWriter fw = null;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter(baseDir);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

Thread  myThread = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            int currentwait = 0;
            int j=0;
            while(currentwait < sleeptimer)
            {
                sleep(200);
                currentwait+=200;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 200 ; i++)
                {
                    if(!cur1.moveToNext())
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    ContactInfo p = new ContactInfo();
                    String content = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("body"));
                    String number = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("address"));
                    long date = cur1.getLong(cur1.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    String protocol = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
                    String name = p.getName(number, c);
                    String type = null;

                    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.clear();
                    cal.setTimeInMillis(date);

                    String date_time=String.format("%1$te %1$tB %1$tY,%1$tI:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp",cal);

                    if( protocol == null )
                    {
                        type = "Outbox";
                    }
                    else
                        type = "Inbox";

                    try{

                        writer.write("Type: " + type);
                        writer.newLine();

                        writer.write("Name: " + number+"<"+name+">");
                        writer.newLine();

                        writer.write("Date: " + date_time);
                        writer.newLine();

                        writer.write("Content: " + content);
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.newLine();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("INFO", e.getMessage().toString());
                    }

                    //Log.i("INFO", content+" "+j);

                    sms[j] = new SMS(type , name , number , date_time , content );
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally{
            try{
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }

            uploadtoserver(baseDir);
        }
    }
};
myThread.start();
```

any idea to improve it ???thanks :)))

Comment: Well, every time you loop through you sleep for 200ms. Why is that?

Comment: Try to output in file the string returned by function. Don't assign it to other string , this will save at least few seconds.
Second optimization could be to use an internal cache, don't write directly to flash.

Comment: without threading loop breaks after 400-500 iterations logcat shows "failed to call dumpstate" and process died. By threading its working but takes time

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line:

```
sleep(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [setMaxSqlCacheSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setMaxSqlCacheSize%28int%29) to increase the cache size. Default is 10. Try setting 20 first and see whether the time reduces to half..

*Or/And*

You can execute this sqlite query before performing any operation on db and see if that improves the speed. Changing the temp store to `memory` should improve the read write speed..

```
PRAGMA temp_store = 2; /* 0 | DEFAULT | 1 | FILE | 2 | MEMORY; */
```

When temp_store is MEMORY (2) temporary tables and indices are kept in as if they were pure in-memory databases memory

Also

```
PRAGMA page_size = bytes;
```

Query or set the page size of the database. The page size must be a power of two between 512 and 65536 inclusive.

Probably you can pass these statements either to `execSQL(String sql)` or to `query()`. Try and let me know how it works.

Check out other PRAGMAs that Sqlite supports: [http://www.sqlite.org/](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum)

---

### Update:

From documentation of `query` API:

For best performance, the caller should follow these guidelines:

- Provide an explicit *projection*, to prevent reading data from storage that aren't going to be used.
- Use question mark parameter markers such as *`'phone=?'`* instead of explicit values in the *selection* parameter, so that queries that differ only by those values will be recognized as the same for caching purposes.

Comment: Also remove the Sleep call.. :)

Comment: Thats not help in my case Im reading sms records sqlite not gonna help because we can not read other applications data.